# Can we call joinpoint.proceed with arguments in Spring AOP

Tags: aop, spring-aop

I am trying to call joinpoint.proceed with batches of arguments. 
Is it possible to call.

I am not able to find any examples where we are partitioning the arguments or making new arguments then calling joinpoint.proceed on them.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and show sample code which explains what you want to do. Your question is unclear and people have to guess what you want, as you can se in R.G's answer. Analysis and a subsequent precise answer are much preferable to a guess, though. So please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and the write one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
@Service
public class AdditionService {
    public Integer sum(List<Integer> list) {
        Integer sum = 0;
        for (Integer i : list) {
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum :" + sum);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

and an aspect to find sum in batches

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExampleAspect {
    @Around("execution(* com.package..*.sum*(..)) && within(com.package..*) && args(list)")
    public Integer around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, List<Integer> list) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = pjp.getArgs(); // get the arguments array
        Integer sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 5) {
            args[0] = (list.subList(i, i + 5)); // modify the arguments array
            System.out.println(args[0]);
            sum += (Integer) pjp.proceed(args);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

the service bean accessed like following

```
Integer[] a= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
Integer sum = 0;
sum = service.sum(Arrays.asList(a));
System.out.println("Total : "+sum);
```

would print the following to console

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Sum :15
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Sum :40
Total : 55
```

Hope this helps